# Xamarin: Some resource id still sitting inside the generated file in Resource Designer.cs

Tags: xamarin, resources, android-resources

why Resource designer.cs file contain a id which I can't find it on my solution project.

```
global::SharedLibrary.Resource.Id.btnSave = global::blah blah .Resource.Id.btnSave;
```

When I search through the file in my solution, the btnSave id still sitting in the Resource Designer.cs file but couldn't find it in my Solution. I tried to clean the project but the error still there.

Do anyone here can see what the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to completely regenerate the `Resource.designer.cs` file. To do so, delete your current `Resource.designer.cs` file. Clean and rebuild the project, then ensure you have "Show all files" enabled, and include the newly generated `Resource.designer.cs` file.